# Button working only for the first row

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've put button in my table EDIT column but the button is working only for the first row click event. I am trying to open pop up window on button click. The pop up is opened only for the first row button click only.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($books as $data)
     <tr>
         <td> {{$data['BookID']}} </td>
         <td> {{$data['BookName']}} </td>
         <td> {{$data['BookUnitPrice']}} </td>
         <td><button type="button" value="EDIT" style="height:20px;" id="myBtn"></button></td>
         <td> {{$data['BookUnitPrice']}} </td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

javascript code

```
<script>
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Need more description about your question,btw `myBtn` in your code all buttons has the same id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created multiple buttons with the same id, which is not really allowed since the id is meant to be a **unique** identifier for an element. You could give each button its own unique id and then listen to all of them but the far easier thing to do is listen for event bubbling:

```
<tbody id="button-parent">
    @foreach($books as $data)
     <tr>
         <td> {{$data['BookID']}} </td>
         <td> {{$data['BookName']}} </td>
         <td> {{$data['BookUnitPrice']}} </td>
         <td><button type="button" value="EDIT" style="height:20px;"></button></td>
         <td> {{$data['BookUnitPrice']}} </td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); //I am assuming that this actually is unique
    var btnContainer = document.getElementById("button-parent");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btnContainer.onclick = function(e) {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        // if you need to know which button was pressed then it's e.target
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

select table in javascript (jquery) and loop through all table rows.Then add event listener of click on that button and perform any action you want.

```
$('table tr').each((i,element), () => {
  $(`${element} td button`).click(() => {
    // perform any action you want
  });
});
```

Comment: It's not reasonable to assume that OP uses jQuery when there's no tag or code that relates to jQuery

Comment: But laravel uses bootstrap which use jquery

Comment: Only if you use the bootstrap boilerplate. You can always opt to not use it.

Comment: @RehmanMehar A lot do, most don't. It's a big world out there in the land of css frameworks. https://github.com/troxler/awesome-css-frameworks/blob/master/readme.md